# How to send and receive fragmented data with System.Net.WebSockets

Tags: c#, asynchronous, networking, .net-core, websocket

I'm looking for a reference on how to correctly use `WebSocket.ReceiveAsync()` and `WebSocket.SendAsync()` with fragmented data, when the transferred message is larger than the allocated buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the methods I'm using. Not sure if they cover all the cases, but works for me at the moment. Will appreciate any tips for improvements.

### Allocate Buffers

```cs
const int bufferSize = 1024;
readonly byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
readonly byte[] sendBuffer = new byte[bufferSize];
```

### Wait/Receive Message

```cs
async Task<string> WaitMessageAsync (CancellationToken token)
{
    using var stream = new MemoryStream();
    var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(receiveBuffer);
    var result = default(WebSocketReceiveResult);
    do
    {
        result = await WebSocket.ReceiveAsync(segment, token);
        if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
            throw new OperationCanceledException();
        stream.Write(segment.Array, segment.Offset, result.Count);
    } while (!result.EndOfMessage);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(stream.ToArray());
}
```

### Send Message

```cs
async Task SendMessageAsync (string message, CancellationToken token)
{
    var messageLength = message.Length;
    var messageCount = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)messageLength / bufferSize);
    for (var i = 0; i < messageCount; i++)
    {
        var offset = bufferSize * i;
        var count = bufferSize;
        var lastMessage = i + 1 == messageCount;
        if (count * (i + 1) > messageLength)
            count = messageLength - offset;
        var segmentLength = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message, offset, count, sendBuffer, 0);
        var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(sendBuffer, 0, segmentLength);
        await WebSocket.SendAsync(segment, WebSocketMessageType.Text, lastMessage, token);
    }
}
```

### Close Connection

To close the connection in a proper way (with handshake):

```cs
WebSocket.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.NormalClosure, "", token);
```